# enough using checksum

Tags: hash, checksum

How would you do that?

You are sending files which contains many lines.Every line is a record from database.

All files are zipped toggether into one file. Is it enough to send a checksum with this file to ensure that other side received all records and none has disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A checksum would change if any contents of the file were malformed or missing, so by comparing the checksums, the recipient can be sure that the files were received fully and not damaged. After all, that is the entire purpose of the checksum.

If you are worried about attackers, I would not send the checksum with the files, as an attacker could intercept both the file and the checksum, change the file, modify the checksum to allow the modifications to appear valid, and send the file on its way.

Like other posters have said, however, the major packaging formats contain a built-in checksum for validation of the contents.

Answer (score 2):

There's usually a built-in checksum in most packing formats (gzip, zip, ...) so it is not necessary to add one if you only want to check if the file has not been physically damaged during the transfer.

Comment: Like I said to Indeera's answer, a checksum can be used to continually verify the contents, which provides an added benefit to the checksum produced by the packaging formats.

Comment: True. I did not think about the security aspect. However, if you want to enforce file integrity through checksums, you need to have a  reliable source for them. As far as I know, checksums are used to validate a file as genuine wherever it comes from, usually by checking the file against a checksum you obtained from a legit source.

If you send the checksums along with the files, what would prevent an attacker from extracting files, modifying them, recalculating their checksum and zip everything back ? Unless you use an obscure checksum algorithm of course...

Answer (score 1):

If it's zipped you're sending only one file. If the zip file is not received properly, you would not be able to open it. Internally zipped archives manage their own checksums to ensure the data integrity.

Comment: However, checksums have the added benefit of being used at any time. I could unzip, change the contents, and rezip using the same compression algorithm and the file would be fine. The checksum would let me know things have changed. It provides another layer of validation.

Comment: Assuming the 'middleman' didn't intercept the checksum as well and updated it to reflect the changes.

Comment: I should update my post. Generally, you don't send the checksum WITH the file, but make it available for use.

Comment: Generally if that's the requirement, then encryption should be used.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of "disappear" you are trying to protect against.  If it's just random errors, then a checksum is fine.  On the other hand, if it's a malicious attacker deliberately disappearing records, then a checksum is insufficient and you need a MAC.

Comment: A checksum would still protect against a malicious attacker removing records as any modification to the zip would change the checksum.

Comment: Checksums are not designed to protect against malicious agents - it is trivial for the attacker to either modify one of the remaining records so that the checksum checks out - or simply replace it too (since it is transmitted through the same channel).